# Formatting date input box with object being passed in using Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table that was generated dynamically using Vuejs.  It has input elements in cells that render as readOnly.  Each element has an 'edit' button and when it is click, it changes to 'save' and enables the input elements of that row for editing.  When save is clicked, I would like to capture the new value entered and the previous value.  I formatted my date field as `mm/dd/yy` from the original which is in this format `2019-10-10T07:00:00Z`  I am able to successfully format the date using momentjs but it doesn't seem to stick.  The value entered is different from when I alert it.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?  Do I need to refactor my code to allow me to do this because this has to be done for each field, which is to get access to new value and previous value.

```
<div id="app">
<table border=1 width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td>EDIT</td>
    <td v-for="editableKey in editableKeys" :key="editableKey" class="label">{{ editableKey }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr v-for="(program, index) in programs">
    <td><button v-if="program.isReadOnly" v-on:click="editItem(program)">edit</button>&nbsp;<button @click="saveItem(program)" v-else>save</button></td>    
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="formatDate(program)"></td>  
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.company"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.funding"></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.funded"></td>
    <td><select :class="bgColor(program)" type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :disabled="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.Recruit">
            <option>Internal</option>
            <option>Recruiting</option>
        </select>
      <!--<input  :class="bgColor(program)" type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.Recruit">--></td>
    <td><input type="text" v-on:change="" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.program"></td>    
  </tr>
</table>

</div>



new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    programs: [],
    editableKeys: ['date', 'company', 'funding', 'funded', 'recruit', 'program'],
  }),
  created () {
    this.getPrograms();
  },
  methods: {
    getPrograms() {
     axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs").then(response => {
       this.programs = response.data.map(program => ({
           ...program,
           isReadOnly: true
       }));
      }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
      });
    },
    editItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = false
    },
    saveItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = true
      console.log(program)
      alert("New Value: "+program.Date)
      alert("Previous Value: "+program.Date)
    },
    bgColor (program) {
      return program.funded === program.funding ? 'yellow' : 'white'
    },
    formatDate(program){
      var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
      var format2digitYear = formatL.replace(/YYYY/g,'YY');
      return moment(program.Date).format(format2digitYear);
    },
    updateField(program){
      console.log(program)
      alert(program)
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG) for some clarity.
Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to behave in a way that the data in the input is different than what is being shown you'll have to decouple the input from the data.

`v-model` needs to havea a variable assigned so that the input can update its value. Right now you're using `v-model="formatDate(program)"` which **cannot** work, because passing a static result of the function cannot be reactive.

There are several ways of accomplishing this. Here is an example that *just gets it done*. There's certainly room for improvement and alternative implementations...

#### replace `v-model` with `value` and event listeners

This defines where the value comes from; a function generating a formated date. (*note that using a function in template for rendering is not good practice. it's better to do this once and use a cached value, so that the value doesn't have to be recalculated*)

```html
<input
  type="text"
  v-bind:data-id="program.id"
  :readonly="program.isReadOnly"
  :value="formatDate(program)"
  @input="updateDate($event, program)"
>
```

#### update methods

```js
    editItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = false
      program.tempDate = null; // added tempDate to be set to null initially
    },
    saveItem (program) {
      program.isReadOnly = true
      if(program.tempDate !== null) {
        // if tempDate is set, update Date
        program.Date = program.tempDate;
        // and clear tempDate
        program.tempDate = null;
      }
      console.log({...program})
    },
    // new method to convert value of the input from string to Date (if date passed is valid)
    updateDate(e, program ) {
      if(new Date(e.target.value).toString() !== 'Invalid Date'){
        program.tempDate = new Date(e.target.value)
      } else {
        program.tempDate = null
      }
    },
```

## update

As mentioned, using functions to format values in template is not a good idea. Instead, reformat the data before you use it (see map function)
once it is in the right format, you can use `v-model` just note that this example does not check for correctness of date format.

```js
function toDDMMYY(date) {
  const [y, m, d] = (new Date(date)).toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-')
  return `${d}/${m}/${y%100}`
}
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      test: "hello",
      programs: "",
      hide: true,
      editable: [],
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.getPrograms();
  },
  methods: {
    getPrograms: function() {
      axios.get("https://my-json-server.typicode.com/isogunro/jsondb/Programs").then((response) => {
          this.programs = response.data.map(row => ({
            ...row,
            dateFormatted: toDDMMYY(row.Date),
            editable: false
          }));
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.0/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table border=1 width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td width=10px>EDIT</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Program</td>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>Funding</td>
      <td>Funded</td>
      <td>Recruit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="program in programs">
      <td>
        <button v-if="program.editable == false" @click="program.editable = true">edit</button>
        <button v-else @click="program.editable = false">save</button>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.dateFormatted"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.program"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.company"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.funding"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.funded"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="!program.editable" v-model="program.Recruit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I definitely don't want to do anything that isn't good practice so I think I will refactor it not to use objects, which is how I started out.  I just couldn't figure out how to makes the input elements readOnly until edit was clicked.  Here was my original [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/WNNOMeB)  Any thoughts?

Comment: what are you planning on doing with the data? Are you going to be sending it to another API? individually or as group?

Comment: I'm using it with SharePoint so I plan on saving it into a SharePoint list.  Saving it into a list is not a problem, I just need to capture the new value entered into the input and the previous value.

Comment: For the date field, ```mm/dd/yy```.  The others will be as is.  In my real application, I have more than one date field

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot!  Makes sense.  The spread operator is new to me, so I didn't even realize you can reformat the date before use.  That is good to know.

Comment: you don't _have_ to use a spread operator. you could also do `Object.assign` to make a copy and add additional props.

Comment: Ok. How would I do that?  I'm looking at ```Object.assign()``` on MDN and I don't even know where to begin.  What would be the equivalent of what you did with the spread operator?

Comment: `Object.assign({}, row, {dateFormatted: toDDMMYY(row.Date), editable: false})`, the first empty object (`{}`) is there for immutability, it can be skipped

Comment: Ok. Thank you for that.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but I get an error when I try to use the ```Object.assign()```. What am I doing wrong?  [PEN](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/MWWEeeJ?editors=1011)

Comment: it's because the arrow function was setup to expect an object `()=>({})` take out the `({` before and the `})` after

Comment: Got it.  Thanks!